# Add an interface subtype to a component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'd like to add an "interface subtype" to a component, for example:

```
@Component
export default class Graph extends Vue
{

    @Prop ()
    public data: Array<Graph.Data> ;

}
```

with a sub-interface like:

```
export interface Data
{
    time: Date
    value: number
}
```

in order to enforce the caller to provide correctly formatted props:

```
<graph :data="data" />
```

here `data` being of type `Array<Graph.Data>`.

Any idea...?

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript does not support inner interfaces, but you can use `namespace`/`module` to achieve what you want:

```
@Component
class Graph extends Vue
{

    @Prop()
    public data: Array<Graph.Data>;

}
namespace Graph {
    export interface Data  {
        time: Date
        value: number
    };
}
export default Graph;

// example variable
var someData: Array<Graph.Data> = [];
```

See [**TypeScript playground demo**](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%20Click%20%22Options%22%20and%20tick%20something%20for%20the%20false-positive%20error%20go%20away%0D%0Afunction%20Component(x)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Afunction%20Prop()%3A%20PropertyDecorator%20%7B%20return%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Vue%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%40Component%0D%0Aclass%20Graph%20extends%20Vue%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%40Prop()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20data%3A%20Array%3CGraph.Data%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Anamespace%20Graph%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20interface%20Data%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20time%3A%20Date%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aexport%20default%20Graph%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20example%20variable%0D%0Avar%20someData%3A%20Array%3CGraph.Data%3E%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B).